# pyplot: Closing a show() window doesn't continue code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have successfully been using pyplot to show heatmaps.  Today it seems to have stopped working.

My problem is that setting up my plot, then calling the `show()` method shows the figure in a window, but when I close this window (by clicking the x at the top), my code doesn't continue past where the `show()` method is called. It seems to hang on `show()`.

`matrix` is a numpy matrix.

This is an example of my code:

```
plt.pcolor(matrix, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.xlabel('xaxis', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('yaxis', fontsize=20)
plt.axis([0, matrix.shape[1], 0, matrix.shape[0]])
plt.colorbar()
#This is where my code hangs...
plt.show()
#Closing the window manually does nothing.
#And the close() method doesn't seem to do anything.
plt.close()
```

After the `show()` method is called, and the window is closed, my process keeps going, and I have to manually terminate it.

Does anyone know the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using this in ipython? What OS are you working on? Have you changed anything in your script or updated any packages that could have caused the problem? Could you provide a bit more details?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using tkinter:

I ran into the same problem when using tkinter (to select the file with the data for the plots) in conjunction with pyplot. I have found that, by calling `root.destroy` on my `tkinter.Tk()` object, closing the window created by `plt.show()` allows my code to continue instead of hanging.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting `plt.ion()` sometime before `plt.show()`. That should set interactive mode, and `show` won't stop the execution of your script.

Comment: When I add `plt.ion()` before `plt.show()`, the window appears briefly (long enough to see the figure, actually), and then closes by itself.

Comment: @Kestrel Well in that case it closes because you call `plt.close()`.

Comment: This solution is a work-around, but not an answer to the question why `show` continues to block after closing the figure.

Comment: Agreed, just thought it might be useful in this case

Comment: @hitzg even when `plt.close()` is removed, it still exhibits the same blocking behaviour.

Comment: @Kestrel I was referring to your first comment

Answer (score 0):

because `plt.show()` is a "blocking function" and the code will not resume until you close the figure. it will not even get to `plt.close()` before you close the figure, as it is written after `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Just recently it looks as though you can do:

```
plt.show(block=False)
```

This will no longer block the code from continuing after the graph is closed.